# keep grid aligned despite character width

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS grid inside a `<section>` tag. I need to somehow align a series of `<h3>` tags despite the width of a character. See the example below:

```css
.letter-grid__authors-titles {
  display: flex;
}

.filter-item-grid {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

.letter-grid__filter-item {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.alphabet {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 73px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #484848;
}
```

```html
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">e</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">j</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">k</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">w</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

You'll see that all of the "titles" are not aligned vertically, because the characters are slightly different widths. I tried adding in a margin, along with playing around with the text centering but am not entirely sure that is the way to go about it.

How best can I have the titles aligned with each other?

Comment: Add a min width that is the size of your widest character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a min width that is the size of your widest character:

```
.alphabet {
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

I have used 100px in this example, just replace it with the actual width of your widest character (typically the W).

```css
.letter-grid__authors-titles {
  display: flex;
}

.filter-item-grid {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

.letter-grid__filter-item {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.alphabet {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 73px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #484848;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">e</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">j</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">k</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">w</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code:

```
.alphabet {
        width: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to specify a default width to your `.alphabet` div.

This way your element will take the same space no matter what letter you can put.

Here I put `width: 10rem;` so you can see.

If you need something more generic maybe you will need to rearrange your elements and use something like `display: contents`. you can check this cool tutorial: https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/

```css
.letter-grid__authors-titles {
  display: flex;
}

.filter-item-grid {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
}

.letter-grid__filter-item {
  display: grid;
  display: -ms-grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  margin-left: 24px;
}

.alphabet {
  align-self: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 73px;
  width: 10rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #484848;
}
```

```html
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">e</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">j</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">k</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="letter-grid__authors-titles">
  <span class="alphabet">w</span>
  <div class="filter-item-grid">
    <div class="letter-grid__filter-item">
      <h3 class="letter-grid__filter-title">
        <a href="#">Title</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **table display** (`table`, `table-row`, `table-cell`) like this:

```css
.main {
  display: table;
}

.main section {
  display: table-row;
}

.main section div {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <section>
    <div class="letter">
      <h1>AAA</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <ul>
        <li>Title 1</li>
        <li>Title 2</li>
        <li>Title 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <div class="letter">
      <h1>BBBBBBBBBBBBB</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="titles">
      <ul>
        <li>Title 1</li>
        <li>Title 2</li>
        <li>Title 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bocanegra_carlos/0yowhxmy/